# Higgs decay at higher energies

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, higgs

If I look at the expected Higgs decay BR's vs. $m_H$ the WW and ZZ dominate over the tt decay mode in the over tt threshold region. From the mere couplings:

$g_{ffH} = \sqrt2 m_f /v$

$g_{VVH} = 2 m_V /v$

I would expect the tt (even with the square root) to dominate. Is it correct, that this deviates merely because of phase space, or is there something I'm missing? (Would also explain why the WW decay is more probable than the ZZ)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpcrg.png